# Python Pyramid AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy auto-expired cookies based on inactivity issue

Tags: python, pyramid

Someone please help. I'm new to pyramid. So according to the pyramid docs about [AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/api/authentication.html#pyramid.authentication.AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy)

developers says that we can set up auto-expired cookies based on inactivity - awesome. 
But it doesn't work for me, so it says that you need to use **reissue_time** parameter and set it in pair with **timeout**. If **timeout** is for example set to 1200, so then **reissue_time** should be timout / 10 = 120, 2 minutes.
As i understood the point is to make auto logout after 2 minutes when a user is inactive. But when i try to reload the page token or session is not expiring.

```
#myapp/__init__.py
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config

from myapp.models import initialize_sql
from myapp import views
from pyramid.authentication import AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy
from pyramid.authorization import ACLAuthorizationPolicy


def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    authentication_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy(secret='secret', hashalg='sha512', timeout=1200, reissue_time=120)
    authorization_policy = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()
    config = Configurator(settings=settings, root_factory='myapp.factory.RootFactory', )
    config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
    #config.add_jinja2_renderer('.html', settings_prefix='jinja2.')
    config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.scan('myapp.models')
    config.set_authentication_policy(authentication_policy)
    config.set_authorization_policy(authorization_policy)
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    initialize_sql(engine)
    views.routes(config)
    return config.make_wsgi_app()

#factory/rootfactory.py
from pyramid.security import (
    Allow,
    Authenticated,
    )


class RootFactory(object):
    '''Root factory class. Acl auth system'''

    __acl__ = [(Allow, Authenticated, 'view'),]

    def __init__(self, request):
        pass

#views/__init__.py
def routes(config):

 config.add_route('home', '/')
 config.add_route('login', '/login')
 config.add_route('logout', '/logout')

config.scan('myapp')

#views/auth.py
from pyramid.response import Response
from pyramid.security import remember, forget, authenticated_userid
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPFound, HTTPForbidden

from pyramid.view import view_config, forbidden_view_config

from sqlalchemy.exc import DBAPIError

from ..models import DBSession
from ..models.user import User

from ..forms.login import LoginForm


@view_config(route_name='login', renderer='myapp:templates/login.jinja2')
@forbidden_view_config(renderer='myapp:templates/login.jinja2')
def login_view(request):
    if request.authenticated_userid:
        return HTTPFound(location=request.application_url)
    next = request.params.get('next') or request.route_url('home')
    login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST' and login_form.validate():
        login = request.params.get('login', '')
        password = request.params.get('password', '')
        user = User.by_login(login)
        if user and user.validate_password(password):
            headers = remember(request, login)
            return HTTPFound(location=next, headers=headers)
    return {'form': login_form}


@view_config(route_name='logout', renderer='myapp:templates/logout.jinja2')
def logout_view(request):
    headers = forget(request)
    loc = request.route_url('login')
    return HTTPFound(location=loc, headers=headers)

#views/home.py
from pyramid.security import authenticated_userid
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPForbidden
from pyramid.response import Response
from pyramid.view import view_config

from sqlalchemy.exc import DBAPIError

from ..models import DBSession
from ..models.user import User


@view_config(route_name='home', permission='view', renderer='myapp:templates/base.jinja2')
def home_view(request):

    return Response('Ok')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your session is logged out after *1200* seconds, or 20 minutes. You'll be issued a new cookie at most every 120 seconds, or 2 minutes.

In other words, the `reissue_time` only limits how often a new token is issued. If a user contacts the server very frequently, it would be costly to keep issuing new tokens. Instead, a new token is only issued if the old token is at least `reissue_time` seconds old. A new token will be fresh for another `timeout` seconds, so each re-issue extends the session.

Only if a user contacts the server with a cookie issued more than `timeout` seconds old is the session no longer valid.

Comment: I see, thank you! Then i want to ask, how can i make an auto logout if user wasn't active let's say for several minutes? Using something like middleware or root_factory, i don't want to dupe the code in each view. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3487828: set the `timeout` value to a few minutes; so set it to 300 seconds (5 minutes) for example. This is the maximum time a user is allowed to be inactive before automatically being logged out. Adjust the `reissue_time` accordingly, set it to 30 for example.

Comment: I tried like you said, but it dosen't work like i want. Maybe do you know some way how to make session expire when user is inactive let's say for 5 minutes, and if user do something and sending some requests, session will not expire after 5 minutes, it just restart counter.

Comment: That is how it works right now. I can't see exactly what you are doing on your server (did you restart it correctly, for example) so I can't see what you are doing wrong on your side.

Comment: Yeah i  it's hard to understand because you need to see what i'm doing. Are you sure that playing with these values: "authentication_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy(secret='secret', hashalg='sha512', timeout=300, reissue_time=30)" do the point - auto-expire auth ticken when user is inactive only or maybe you know some other technique. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I am sure, those settings configure the tokens to auto-expire.

Comment: Ok thanks, Then i can capture video for you of what i'm doing, also show you installed packages and etc, ok?